# How to create an app like youtube for dowload and show video

Tags: android

YouTube after the download file, just show it in the youtube app
. Where the file is stored and how it can be created application that open my videos and files in my application

Comment: Please provide more detail. What have you tried?

Comment: show video only in my app

Answer (score 0):

You can use Room database in your app to store your files and it will apperar on your mobile storage or anything go and search for it